# AnyObject does not have a member named "sort"

Tags: ios, arrays, sorting, swift

I have an array `var savedDataArray: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedDataArray")G` which I want to sort ascending

Im checking if its empty, then unwrapping it, however i'm still getting the "does not have a member named" error?

```
if savedDataArray?.count>0{
            savedDataArray!.sort{$0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
        }
```

error `Any object does not have a member named "sort"`

So then i tried reversing the `array` and big surprise the same error for `.reverse`

I thought by checking if the array is `nil`, then force unwrapping, these errors wouldnt be relevant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't access the array as an "AnyObject". Try pulling it as an Array object.

```
var savedDataArray: Array<String>? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("savedDataArray") as? Array<String>;
```

Substitute the "String" type for whatever you're pulling the objects in your Array as. This allows you to use the "sort" member.